# Slow connection to Azure Sql Server

Tags: azure, database-performance

I'm moving from a Rackspace Cloud platform to Azure but I'm having some real performance issues. It seems like everything is a little but slower but especially database interaction.

I've done some load testing with all the different Scale options for both the CPU and the Sql Database and they only get comparable to the Rackspace account when they're all maxed out which seems excessive. Let me clarify, the Azure system can probably handle more load with it's higher scale options but it's reaction time for one user is slower than Rackspace. I didn't write down what the exact load level was that Azure would be faster than Rackspace but it was much higher than the load we currently have.

I've been asked some specific questions like:  Is the database and the web server in the same datacenter? I'm not sure how to check if they are but it seems like they aren't. Is there an option to have them in the same datacenter?

Another question was: Am I running Sql Server in a VM or using the service?  I did not set up a VM, I went to the Sql Databases tab and created a database.

Is there anything that can improve the database performance for the Azure platform? Any way to decrease latency on connections?

Comment: Data Center (or more accurately *region*) is selected when you create your VMs, cloud services, websites, SQL Database services, etc. For example, they might be in West Europe or East US. If they're not in the same region, you'll see more latency and incur bandwidth charges. You can easily check this by looking at your database service, SQL service, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then they are both in the same datacenter/region. Both of them have "Central US" as their location.

Answer (score 1):

Try the legacy Web or Business tiers that are going to be retired next year instead of using the new tiers as recommended since the new tiers have performance problems.

You can change over by going to the database dashboard on the Azure portal can changing the setting on the Scaling tab.

In our case for example, a query that completed in <5 sec on the old Web tier takes >7 min to complete on the new Standard tier. Even very simple queries that do not involve any joins and return little data are extremely slow. The problem seems exponentially worse as the table size increases, with queries against very small tables virtually unaffected while queries executed against larger tables grind to a complete halt in many cases. The legacy tiers do not suffer from this problem. They are going to be retired but, hopefully, the performance problems with the new tiers will be resolved before then.

Comment: Same issue with me. With a sql server running on a vm, we pretty much know where time spent during a query, or at least we know which part took it, we know the network latency is predictable, but, with the azure database in a black box, we have no idea what happen behind the scene. Don't know why it will take so long for a database connection. Seems like, if you don't use the database for a while, it will have huge latency for the first query. Hopefully MS is aware of the performance issue with azure database. We like cloud, but not a slow cloud.

Comment: Any updates on this it is 2016? Still having same issues slow Azure SQL